# When is The GIMP gonna let me save ( not export ) .jpg, .png, etc.?

Tags: jpeg

When is The GIMP gonna let me save ( not export ) .jpg, .png, etc.?
Not Why Not, Just tell me when. Having to export the most common graphic file extensions in the world is Jejune.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, "export" and "save as" are (roughly) the same thing. Some programs (like Photoshop) use "save as", others (like The GIMP) say "export". But they effectively do the same thing: save in a non-native format.

Answer (score 1):

Probably never, since this was a change made in 2.8 to avoid destructive formats in which you could save your project (so you won't lose your layers).

You could swap the "export as" shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+E) to the "save as" one (Ctrl+Shift+S) if that bothers you so much.

More info about that [here](https://www.gimp.org/release-notes/gimp-2.8.html#save-and-export) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332994/gimp-2-8-doesnt-allow-to-save-usual-image-file-formats-jpg-png-via-save-dial)